# Javascript function scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope, public

Why does the alert print 2 in the below example? var a is unknown to function n...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>Test Doc</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = 1;
        function f() {
            var a = 2;
            function n() {
                alert(a);
            }
            n();
        }
        f();
    </script>
</head>

<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"var a is unknown to function n..."* that would be the case in PHP. Luckily JavaScript is not PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript functions inherit their parent's scope. Inner variables shadow parent scope variables with the same name.

[Further Reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures).

Comment: +1 Spot on and good link.  @user443946, search for "Nested functions and closures" within that document.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is decalred as a global variable and given a value of 1. `a` is also declared inside the function `f()` and given a value of 2. Function `n()` is declared inside the function `f()` and called after the assignment to the "inner" `a`.

So when `n` is called, the identifier `a` will be resolved from the scope of `n`. The first variable object on the scope chain with an `a` property is the one declared in `f`, so its value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

It would alert "2".

Test your javascript examples here : [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Your example is pasted here : [your javascript example](http://jsfiddle.net/ePXQK/)

And why the heck is `var a` unknown to n() ??